# How to navigate between Routes basing on Page URL?

Tags: backbone.js, router, backbone-views

I am working on a Backbone Application that contains multiple routes. I would like to modify my changePage function and make it take a hash as a parameter and when it is called it changes the page basing on that URL.

This is my router

```
define(["jquery","backbone",'views/header'],  function( $, Backbone, Header) {
var ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    _header: null,
    routes: {
         "": "login",
         "home": "home",
        },
    initialize: function() { 
        this.firstPage = true;
        this.fromBack = false;
        i18n.currentLocal = localStorage.getItem("currentLocal") || 'en';
        Backbone.history.start();         
    },
    login: function() {
        var self = this;        
        require(['views/loginPageView'], function(loginView){
             self.changePage(new loginView(),true);
        });         
    },
    home: function() {
        var self = this;        
        require(['views/homePageView'], function(homeView){
             self.changePage(new homeView(),false);
        });         
    },
    changePage: function (page,noPanel) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $page = $(page.el);
        $page.attr('data-role', 'page');
        console.log(this.firstPage);
        if(this.firstPage){
            $('#pageContent').append($page);
             page.render();
             if(!noPanel){
                 self._header = new Header({parent: $("#header")});
             }
        }
        else{
            $('#pageContent').html($page);
            $("#header").empty();
            page.render();
        }
        if (this.firstPage) {
            this.firstPage = false;
        }
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred;
    },

    });

return ApplicationRouter;
})
```

This is the First View :

define([ "jquery", "backbone","text!../../pages/login.html"], function($, Backbone,loginTpl) {

```
var loginPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events :{
        "click #login" : "login",
        "change input[type=radio]":"changeLanguage"
    },
    initialize : function() {
    //Some Code
    },
     render: function() {
            this.template = _.template(loginTpl);
            $(this.el).html(this.template);
            return this;
        },
        login:function(){
            console.log("Login Clicked");
            router.navigate('home', {trigger: false, replace: false});
        },
        changeLanguage:function(){
            //console.log("change lang");
            if(i18n.currentLocal == 'en'){
                i18n.currentLocal='fr';
                this.render();
                $("#month2").attr('checked',true);
            }else
                {
                if(i18n.currentLocal == 'fr'){
                    i18n.currentLocal='en';
                    this.render();

                }       
                }
        }

});

return loginPageView;
```

});

So instead of using router.navigate which caused some problems due to bugs in the router I think, I would like to use router.changePage('home.html'); 
and based on the URL I load to respective View. 
Thank You

Comment: Your `changePage()` does much more a mere `navigate()` would do. Can you please explain what problems `navigate()` was causing (expected vs. actual results, errors, side effects)?

Comment: Yes my changePage is responsible for loading the views and rendering the pages. When I use navigate() I am obliged to use the route name and the behavior of the backbutton is wrong it should be clicked twice in order to go back to the previous page also the view that I intent to navigate to gets called twice and I don't know why !